# A couple of questions about Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I have a couple of questions:

1. Are my files safe when I upgrade (from the update manager) from 12.04 to 13.04? Are my files safe if I upgrade from the 13.04 install disc?
2. Are my files safe if I dual-boot windows with Ubuntu?
3. Can I use multi-boot? More than two OSs on my hard disk (3TB, 2TB, 1TB)
4. Is there a book for transitioning from windows to Ubuntu?

Also, could you answer without using any technical jargon? I'm a newbie to Ubuntu.

Comment: I'd advice you to update your question to include one specific question, so that it can be answered effectively.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't write in all caps - that is considered rude. Also keep it to one question per post. And at last but not least, this is not the right place for urgent matters - this is not a call centre. See [How do we deal with “urgent!” questions?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5849/88802). I've voted-to-close your question because it's not fit for this site as it stands.

Comment: To answer in short, yes, yes, yes, and yes. For the last question take a look here http://ubuntu-manual.org/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Answer (score 2):

1. In short, it **is** safe. But you should **always** have a backup of your data available.
2. Of course, no matter if you installed Ubuntu using [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) (Installer through Windows) or at onother partition in your hard drive.
3. [Dual Booting Windows and Ubuntu (from the Ubuntu Help page)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)
4. You can have a look at the [Ubuntu Manual](http://ubuntu-manual.org) which is available for free.